# How would I do this with CSS?

Tags: css

How might I make the 1, 2, 3 in CSS? This would be trivial if I just  included an image, but I'm interested in doing it completely with CSS.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Divs with rounded corners. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: google "step progress bar css"

Comment: `<ol>` plus some rules to rotate the list like that.

Comment: We cannot produce the code for you. If you have tried and received an error, please post it.

Comment: Agreed it's not the best constructed of questions, but two people have managed to produce decent answers based on the information the OP has provided, so I've voted to re-open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a demo for your request:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="circle" style="float:left">1</div>
    <div class="circle" style="float: right;">3</div>
    <div class="circle">2</div>
</div>

.form-group {
    background:linear-gradient(to top,#cccccc,#cccccc) repeat-x center;
    background-size:2px 2px;
    min-width:40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;


}
.circle {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background: white;
    margin:auto;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gui47/11mhutt6/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way for sure but maybe it can inspire you

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 464px;
}
.wrapper::before {
  position: relative;
  top: 9px;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  content: "";
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
span:nth-child(2),
span:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
```